# Counting number of cells based on month of a date

Tags: excel

I am trying to count ¨"the number of stops during each month", and then place them in another table that contain the header as the months (Data Format).

I tried many formulas, in E5:

1. =COUNTIFS(A:A;"=GRP 1";MONTH(B:B);"=1")
2. =COUNTIFS(A:A;"=GRP 1";MONTH(B:B);=1)
3. =COUNTIFS(A:A;"=GRP 1";MONTH(B:B);"MONTH(E4)")

[image]

The error message is the following:

[image]

Any one has an idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `criteria_range` argument for the `COUNTIFS` function generally needs to be a `range`, and not an array.  Hence your formula will fail.

You can use a Pivot table.

- Drag the `Group Number` to the rows area
- Drag  `Date of Stop` to the Columns area
- Drag `Date of Stop` to the Values area
- Format as desired

[image]

For a formula solution, you can use `SUMPRODUCT`.  You have to exclude the first row, or add an additional criteria as text entries will result in a `#VALUE!` error

```
E5: =SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$200=$D5)*(MONTH($B$2:$B$200)=MONTH(E$4)))
```

Note that in your results table, the `Date` row are real dates formatted to show as they appear.

[image]

Or, if your data is in a table, you can use structured references.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((Table1[[Group Number]:[Group Number]]=$D5)*(MONTH(Table1[[Date of Stop]:[Date of Stop]])=MONTH(E$4)))
```

### Edit:

As an exercise, it is possible to use whole column references, as shown in the formula below which tests to ensure that the column B entries are dates.

However, this will significantly increase calculation times, and is rather inefficient.  You are much better off avoiding this by:

- Excluding Row 1, or
- Using a dynamic range reference, or
- Using a `Table` with structured references

---

```
=SUMPRODUCT((IF(ISNUMBER(B:B),A:A,0)=$D5)*(MONTH(IF(ISNUMBER(B:B),B:B,0))=MONTH(E$4)))
```

Since this is an array formula, you need to "confirm" it by holding down <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> while hitting <kbd>enter</kbd>.  If you do this correctly, Excel will place braces `{...}` around the formula as observed in the formula bar

Comment: The first formula worked when excluding the first line. However, I am still with the doubt of including the full column in the formula, eg.MONTH(B:B), it is not possible to overcome this problem?

Comment: See edit. You are much better off not using whole column references, as this will increase the calculation times.

Answer (score 0):

New code.

Think we will have to use EDATE for this formula. For cell(E5) try the following.

```
=COUNTIFS($A:$A,"GRP "&RIGHT($D5,1),$B:$B,">="&E$4,$B:$B,"<"&EDATE(E$4,1))
```

Basically EDATE allows you to get the same date (e.g 1st of the month) as many months in advance a you need. In this case, we set EDATE to 1 month in advance.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but trying both formulas gave the same previous error in the picture.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld: thanks. Code updated to reflect working version.

Comment: @salamabdeen: Updated formula.